# Pass an explicit string to fmt.Sprint in Golang

Tags: string, go

After reading the docs and having a look through the source code, I'm a little unsure if there are any benefits of passing an explicit string to the `fmt.Sprint` function?

For example, will this:

```
return fmt.Sprint("this is a string")
```

be more beneficial than doing this:

```
return "this is a string"
```

Am I correct in thinking that this function works better with types that conform to the Stringer interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Sprint` is pretty much useless for a single string, it should be used if you have a bunch of objects, Stringers or not. It just concatenates the string representations of them. from TFM:

> Sprint formats using the default formats for its operands and returns
>   the resulting string. Spaces are added between operands when neither
>   is a string.

So if you have just one string it's useless. If you have many arguments, especially variadic, it sure beats doing something like `fmt.Sprintf("%v %v %v", foo, bar, baz)`, especially if you don't know how many elements you have.